# Neo4j CSV file import Error

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'am trying to import the '|' delimited csv file into neo4j and it returning the below mentioned error. "Tried to read a field larger than buffer size 2097152. A common cause of this is that a field has an unterminated quote and so will try to seek until the next quote, which ever line it may be on. This should not happen if multi-line fields are disabled, given that the fields contains no new-line characters. This field started at C:\Users\10077\Documents\Neo4j\default.graphdb\import\customer.csv:0" Please help me to resove this....

Comment: can you paste the first ten lines of your csv along in the question, thanks

Comment: O_ORDERKEY,O_CUSTKEY,O_ORDERSTATUS,O_TOTALPRICE,O_ORDERDATE,O_ORDERPRIORITY,O_CLERK,O_SHIPPRIORITY,O_COMMENT
1,36901,O,173665.47,02-01-1996,5-LOW,Clerk#000000951,0,nstructions sleep furiously among 
2,78002,O,46929.18,01-12-1996,1-URGENT,Clerk#000000880,0, foxes. pending accounts at the pending silent asymptot
3,123314,F,193846.25,14-10-1993,5-LOW,Clerk#000000955,0,sly final accounts boost. carefully regular ideas cajole carefully. depos
4,136777,O,32151.78,11-10-1995,5-LOW,Clerk#000000124,0,sits. slyly regular warthogs cajole. regular regular theodolites acro

Comment: So your CSV separator is a coma, not a pipe, no ?

Comment: @logisma yes its comma separated

Comment: Can you share the LOAD CSV statement ?

Comment: @TomGeudens USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///orders.csv" AS row FIELDTERMINATOR '|'
CREATE (:ORDERS  {OORDERKEY : row.O_ORDERKEY , OCUSTKEY: row.O_CUSTKEY,
OORDERSTATUS: row.O_ORDERSTATUS,OTOTALPRICE: row.O_TOTALPRICE, OORDERDATE:
row.O_ORDERDATE, OORDERPRIORITY: row.O_ORDERPRIORITY,OCLERK: row.O_CLERK, 
OSHIPPRIORITY: row.O_SHIPPRIORITY,OCOMMENT: row.O_CO

Comment: So, if it is comma separated (as you say and as is visible), why do you use fieldterminator '|' ?

Comment: @TomGeudens actually i was trying with both the files getting same error..

Comment: So let me get this straight, you've got two versions of the same file, one comma separated, one pipe separated ? And both give the same error ? Are the lines in the file terminated with a carriage return (\n) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is definitely working :

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///orders.csv" AS row FIELDTERMINATOR ',' 
CREATE (:ORDERS {OORDERKEY : row.O_ORDERKEY , OCUSTKEY: row.O_CUSTKEY, OORDERSTATUS: row.O_ORDERSTATUS,OTOTALPRICE: row.O_TOTALPRICE, OORDERDATE: row.O_ORDERDATE, OORDERPRIORITY: row.O_ORDERPRIORITY,OCLERK: row.O_CLERK, OSHIPPRIORITY: row.O_SHIPPRIORITY,OCOMMENT: row.O_COMMENT});
```

With this data :

```
O_ORDERKEY,O_CUSTKEY,O_ORDERSTATUS,O_TOTALPRICE,O_ORDERDATE,‌​O_ORDERPRIORITY,O_CL‌​ERK,O_SHIPPRIORITY,O‌​_COMMENT
1,36901,O,173665.47,02-01-1996,5-LOW,Clerk#000000951,0,nstru‌​ctions sleep furiously among
2,78002,O,46929.18,01-12-1996,1-URGENT,Clerk#000000880,0, foxes. pending accounts at the pending silent asymptot
3,123314,F,193846.25,14-10-1993,5-LOW,Clerk#000000955,0,sly final accounts boost. carefully regular ideas cajole carefully. depos
4,136777,O,32151.78,11-10-1995,5-LOW,Clerk#000000124,0,sits. slyly regular warthogs cajole. regular regular theodolites acro
```

Can you check your end of line characters ?

Hope this helps,

Regards,
Tom